# Structure Data timeintervals in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to visualize the amount of steps taken over a day. Each datapoint looks simplified like this:

```
{
  startDate: 1481029440000,
  endDate: 1481029920000,
  steps: 31
}
```

I'd like to plot it over an entire day and illustrate the duration but also the grow of step increase. Each datapoint is a separate series as I didn't want to have points connected to each other.

The result looks like what I want except for the styling which I have change. However the performance and zoom into the chart is extremely slow. Might there be a better way to use it? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts is optimised for managing many points, not many series (the work has been start on optimising series, though - as far as I know).

You can use one series with the null points as separators. By default [connecting nulls](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.connectNulls) is disabled.

```
data: (function (data) {
      var d = [], i = 0, len = data.length, point;

      for (; i < len; i++) {
        point = data[i];
        d.push([point.startDate, point.steps], [point.endDate, point.steps]);

        if (i < len - 1) {d.push([point.endDate, null]);}
      }

      return d;
    })(data)
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/7vtd4fzm/

Comment: thanks morganfree! I'll give it a try with my dataset, your example seems to be quite like what I need.